# Is there a simple way to switch between 2 models in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have problem with models in Angular 2. I have 2 models:

```
interface Model1 {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  size: string;
  count: number;
  children: Model2[];
}

interface Model2 {
  id: number;
  parentId: number
  title: string;
  subtitle: string;
  publisher: string;
}
```

I am binding some data with variable by id but there are cases that I use Model1 and sometimes Model2.
If I am trying to declare it with 2 models but it is not working. Is there any way to do that instead of using 'any'?
I try to do something like that:

```
private exampleVaraible: Model1 || Model2;
```

Comment: generics would be a way to do this or a union type

Comment: If you want it to be `Model1 OR Model2` you can use [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types). If you want it to be `Model1 AND Model2` you can use `Model1 & Model2`

Comment: @MikeS might want to click the link you posted, union types would throw errors when you try to access something that isn't in all the types you union together, assuming OP wants to use something besides id.

An intersection might work but then you'll have to always set it with a typecast 
`const model: Model1 & Model2 = { //data } as Model1 & Model2 //or as any` but that's kind of gross.

Comment: @DonaldDuck I did click the link, thank you ;) It boils down to "I'm not sure what the OP wants (yet)", which is why I threw unitons and intersections into the room. If the OP said that this won't be what he wished for, then there's going to be other solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the correct syntax to declare a variable with two type definitions is :

private exampleVaraible: Model1 | Model2;

this.exampleVaraible now can be assigned values like

this.exampleVaraible = {
id: 12121,
subtitle: '232323',
parentId: 2323,
publisher: '2323',
title: '2323'
};

this.exampleVaraible = {
id: 1121212,
name: '22323',
size: '2323',
count: 2323,
children: [ {
id: 12121,
subtitle: '232323',
parentId: 2323,
publisher: '2323',
title: '2323'
}]